# Cannot set MOSI pin low even after ending SPI

Tags: interrupt, pins, spi, atmega

I'm building a battery operated device and must shutoff MOSI pin during sleep because it leaks current through the SD card if I don't (about 400 µA).

Problem is, it won't stay off.  I've looked at SPI documentation and as far as I know I just need to call `spi.end()` then set pinmode to output and finally digitalWrite LOW.  I observe with an oscilloscope that it does go low upon my asking it to but only for about 1 µs (actually it goes low twice within a 5 µs time period).

I've also tried manually setting the pin low using the PORT registers and the behavior is the same... see relevant code:

```
spi.end();  

//pinMode(pin_MOSI, OUTPUT);
//digitalWrite(pin_MOSI, LOW);

//Both above (commented out) and below result in the same behavior -- pin does not stay LOW

DDRB |= B00100000;            //set pin 5 as output
PORTB &= B11011111;           //set output low for pin 5

delay(5000);
```

...As you can see there is a delay to ensure that it isn't being set high by some other code.

Is there some sort of SPI interrupt that automatically sets the pin high again?

### Hardware details:

**MCU:** ATMEGA1284P; 
**Programmer:** Atmel-ICE

---

### **UPDATE (13-Mar-2019):**

I didn't realize that SPI is implemented by Atmel in hardware directly (see datasheet page 105):

> MOSI/PCINT13 – Port B, Bit 5
>   – MOSI: SPI Master Data output, Slave Data input for SPI channel. When the SPI0 is enabled
>   as a slave, this pin is configured as an input regardless of the setting of DDB5. When the SPI
>   is enabled as a master, the data direction of this pin is controlled by DDB5. When the pin is
>   forced to be an input, the pull-up can still be controlled by the PORTB5 bit.

I am currently chasing down this latest information and will hopefully come to a resolution soon.  I will post any progress.

Comment: is it a SD module with logic level conversion?

Comment: @Juraj: No level shifting, straight 3.3 volts to the SD card.

Comment: I thought you using SPI.begin() and SPI.end() to use the embedded hardware from the Arduino IDE. You are bit-banging instead?

Comment: @CrossRoads: I'm using SPIClass from <spi.h>.  I'm assuming that is part of the Arduino core but I'm not certain.  I have successfully gotten it to work by clearing the SPI enable bit (SPE) from the SPCR register so I know the library was not doing it for me.

Comment: @Juraj: I'm using ATmega1284P which is a 3.3 volt MCU -- doesn't have 5 volts.  Thanks!

Comment: my runs at 5V. default here is 5V.

Comment: @Juraj: Good point!  I incorrectly assumed the ATmega1284P was a 3.3 volt part but it can go as high as 5.5 volts -- mine is running at 3.3 volts as that is my designed VCC level.

Comment: You're not running 16 MHz are you? That could be unstable.  Speed grades: 0 - 4MHz @ 1.8 - 5.5V, 0 - 10MHz @ 2.7 - 5.5V, 0 - 20MHz @ 4.5 - 5.5V per the datasheet.

Comment: @CrossRoads: I thought I was running at 8 MHz but upon trying to verify found that indeed I am running at 16 MHz at 3.3 volts!  It had been working fine but no guarantee that there won't be issues!!  Using an external oscillator at 16 MHz -- I've figured out how to add a prescaler to slow the MCU to 8 MHz then changed the F_CPU field in boards.txt so that timing wasn't messed up in the Arduino code.  I think everything is finally working.  Thanks so much for the comment -- it wasn't yet a problem but I'm sure could have become a major issue under certain conditions (like maybe warmer temps)!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indeed, SPI is hardware implemented.  I was able to get the MOSI pin to operate as intended by clearing the SPI enable bit from the SPCR register as follows:

```
SPCR &= 0B10111111;  //disable SPI
```

To re-enable after sleep, I'm assuming I'll just do `SPCR |= 0B01000000;` ...pretty sure that will work but I'll update here if I have to modify my solution.

.

**Perhaps also pertinant information:**

I was using an object of *SPIClass* in *SPI.h* which is from the Arduino core libraries -- for some reason it wasn't disabling SPI in hardware when calling the `spi.end()` method, maybe because there was some other SPI object initialized by some other library.  Here is the source from SPI.cpp for the *end* method:

```
void SPIClass::end() {
  uint8_t sreg = SREG;
  noInterrupts(); // Protect from a scheduler and prevent transactionBegin
  // Decrease the reference counter
  if (initialized)
    initialized--;
  // If there are no more references disable SPI
  if (!initialized) {
    SPCR &= ~_BV(SPE);
    interruptMode = 0;
    #ifdef SPI_TRANSACTION_MISMATCH_LED
    inTransactionFlag = 0;
    #endif
  }
  SREG = sreg;
}
```

The line `SPCR &= ~_BV(SPE);` should have done the job for me but I'm guessing it never got there because `initialized` was probably still non-zero.

Comment: If you didn't have #include <SPI.h> at the top of your sketch, how were you able to use SPI.begin(), SPI.transfer();  etc?

Comment: @CrossRoads: I did have SPI.h included -- sorry if that was not clear.

Comment: I thought I read something about not using the library, but I don't see it now. Perhaps I had two topics confused.  Glad you got it sorted.

Comment: Perhaps the SPI library got improved in the years that passed since this answer was written. `spi.end()` has the desired effect now. Setting/clearing the bit in `SPCR` is still faster though.

Comment: @DmitryGrigoryev: Take a look at the end() method that I copied from the core source files (above toward the end of my answer).  If the member variable 'initialized' (which is defined as uint8_t) is not zero then clearing the SPI enable bit in SPCR never happens.  I think the issue is that one of the libraries I was using called SPI.begin() but never called SPI.end() which means SPI was never able to deactivate.  I ended up rewriting the code without the other libraries and the problem was solved.