# Set SPI MOSI pin to idle low on a Due?

Tags: arduino-due, spi

I have an SPI slave connected to Due. I send the SPI slave into sleep mode. During sleep, I need to pull all pins low, including MOSI. What's the best way to pull the SPI-4 pin low on a Due?

[Here](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/a/62492/13327)'s a similar question but it's about an AVR chip and the answer obviously doesn't apply to SAM3X8 which is an ARM.

Comment: Is it the only slave that is connected to the Due?

Comment: @SimSon Yes it's the only one.

Comment: Then you could disable the SPI and set the MISO pin as output low

Comment: Disable SPI, disable peripheral clock for SPI, change back corresponding pins from alternate functions to normal pin functions and set proper outputs. But you should also disable power for the slave. Otherwise low on its chip select pin means it'll be active

Comment: @KIIV Is SPI-4 available as a digital IO pin? Which one?

Comment: @DmitryGrigoryev There are just two SPI's and another four USARTs with SPI mode. However it doesn't matter, pins are fixed and so alternate functions for that pins. You have to use datasheet for the MCU to figure it all out.

Comment: @KIIV I'm talking about the SPI-4 **pin** available on the [Duo](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/SPI#Connections)

Comment: @DmitryGrigoryev https://www.arduino.cc/en/uploads/Main/arduino-Due-schematic.pdf -> SPI header pin 4 is PA26. So, you have to take a look into datasheet and figure out, how to set/reset it's alternate function

Answer (score 1):

I have managed to set MOSI to low by setting bit 26 in `PIOA->PIO_PER`, `PIOA->PIO_OER` and  `PIOA->PIO_CODR` registers. To use SPI again, bit 26 in `PIOA->PIO_PDR` has to be set (this cancels the effect of `PIOA->PIO_PER`).